# Issues with Restangular and Appgyver Supersonic

Tags: angularjs, restangular, steroids

So I have restangular setup on another controller that works fine, however on that controller I don't need to declare `supersonic`

Working Controller

```
angular
  .module('working')
  .controller("IndexController", function ($scope, Restangular) {
```

Working Model

```
angular.module('working', ['restangular'])
    .config(function(RestangularProvider) {
```

But having issues with this one, and the only difference seems to be having supersonic in there. Can't take that out as using it to grab the view parameters (`supersonic.ui.views.current.params.onValue( function (values) {...`)

NotWorking Controller

```
angular
  .module('notworking')
  .controller('IndexController', function($scope, supersonic, Restangular) {
```

NotWorking Model

```
angular.module('notworking', ['restangular'])
    .config(function(RestangularProvider) {
```

... this gives me `IndexController' is not a function, got undefined` which I think I figured out is because in the model it is trying to recreate the module instead of reference the existing one (as here - [Restangular: Error: Unknown provider: RestangularProvider <- Restangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902309/restangular-error-unknown-provider-restangularprovider-restangular)).

Anyways, if I remove the `['restangular']` then it gives me `Unknown provider: RestangularProvider` which one would expect.

But then when I add it to the controllers initial module creation:

```
angular
  .module('notworking', ['restangular'])
  .controller('IndexController', function($scope, supersonic, Restangular) {
```

... it then gives me `Unknown provider: supersonicProvider <- supersonic`

No doubt this is due to me being a newb with both supersonic, angular, and restangular, but really struggling, anyone?

Comment: if you include supersonic on the working.IndexController, does it starts ok?

Comment: AppGyver dev here - not sure why the Angular code itself might not be working, but if you're not using e.g. `supersonic.bind` or other Angular-specific APIs, you can just use `supersonic` without including it as an Angular service. Just make sure the Supersonic script tag is loaded before Angular.

Comment: Thanks @harsa_ that seemed to do the trick, no only using `supersonic` to grab the params, so removed it and got what I needed to working :) If you want to write that as an answer, I'll accept it, may help someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the Angular code itself might not be working, but if you're not using e.g. `supersonic.bind` or other Angular-specific APIs, you can just use Supersonic without including it as an Angular service. Just make sure the Supersonic script tag is loaded before Angular.